# Swift UIVisualEffectView with UIBlurEffect not working

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to show `UIView` after clicking the floating action button. Once, I clicked the floating action button I need to rendering content view. 
Now if I try to apply `blur effect`, It is not working.

**Here is my code:**

```
fileprivate var parentView: UIView!

self.parentView = view
self.items = items
let bounds = self.parentView.bounds

self.contentView = UIView(frame: bounds)
self.blurVisualEffect = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight))
self.blurVisualEffect.frame = self.contentView.frame
self.contentView.addSubview(self.blurVisualEffect)
```

[Sample Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEjpt.png)

Comment: can you use visual debugger and show some screenshots?

Comment: If you assign the frame from `contentView` to the `blurVisualEffect` view, the x and y coordinates will be intact, so it's possible the `blurVisualEffect` view is being offset enough to not be visible.

Comment: @Lu_ It is showing white screen. but background I have tableview.

Comment: change `self.blurVisualEffect.frame = self.contentView.frame` to `self.blurVisualEffect.frame = self.contentView.bounds`

Comment: @Arash Etemad If I change `.frame` to `.bounds` also I am getting white screen.

Comment: also you should add `self.blurVisualEffect.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]`

Comment: @Arash Etemad it is not working.

Comment: set background color for your `contentView` or set `.clear`

Comment: @Arash Etemad if I set it is showing light orange color. I tried another one like set `.clear` for `.contentView` because my main view controller have tableview. if I command 'contentView' Transperant showing but if I apply visualEffects not working.

Comment: could you attach some screenshots?

Comment: @Arash Etemad Updated please check it

Comment: Do you want to add blur effect on the whole screen under floating buttons?

Comment: @ArashEtemad Yes.

Comment: I can't figure out what you are trying to say by "if I set it is showing light orange color. I tried another one like set .clear for .contentView because my main view controller have tableview. if I command 'contentView' Transperant showing but if I apply visualEffects not working" ! Could you please explain it more clear?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .extraLight)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = self. parentView.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
self.contentView.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```